# How to add "context" to Elastic Search suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building a Enterprise social network.

I want to suggest people to add as friend, based on their title.
For example, the value can be: developer, blogger, singer, barber, bartender ...

My users are saved into ElasticSearch, their titles are saved in the field 'title'.

The current mapping is:

```
title: {
    type: 'text',
    analyzer: 'autocomplete_analyzer',
    search_analyzer: 'autocomplete_analyzer_search'
}
```

and the query is:

```
should: [
    {
        match: {
            title: {
                query: user.title,
                minimum_should_match: '90%',
                boost: 2
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and the analyzers definitions are:

```
indexConfig: {
    settings: {
        analysis: {
            analyzer: {
                autocomplete_analyzer: {
                    tokenizer: 'autocomplete_tokenizer',
                    filter: ['lowercase', 'asciifolding']
                },
                autocomplete_analyzer_search: {
                    tokenizer: 'lowercase',
                    filter: ['asciifolding']
                },
                phrase_analyzer: {
                    tokenizer: 'standard',
                    filter: ['lowercase', 'asciifolding', 'fr_stop', 'fr_stemmer', 'en_stop', 'en_stemmer']
                },
                derivative_analyzer: {
                    tokenizer: 'standard',
                    filter: ['lowercase', 'asciifolding', 'derivative_filter', 'fr_stop', 'fr_stemmer', 'en_stop', 'en_stemmer']
                }
            },
            tokenizer: {
                autocomplete_tokenizer: {
                    type: 'edge_ngram',
                    min_gram: 2,
                    max_gram: 20,
                    token_chars: ['letter', 'digit']
                }
            },
            filter: {
                derivative_filter: {
                    type: 'word_delimiter',
                    generate_word_parts: true,
                    catenate_words: true,
                    catenate_numbers: true,
                    catenate_all: true,
                    split_on_case_change: true,
                    preserve_original: true,
                    split_on_numerics: true,
                    stem_english_possessive: true
                },
                en_stop: {
                    type: 'stop',
                    stopwords: '_english_'
                },
                en_stemmer: {
                    type: 'stemmer',
                    language: 'light_english'
                },
                fr_stop: {
                    type: 'stop',
                    stopwords: '_french_'
                },
                fr_stemmer: {
                    type: 'stemmer',
                    language: 'light_french'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it, the relevance is very good, but they are not enough users matched by this, because of the **'90%' criteria**.

A quick and dirty solution is to lower this criteria to 50% of course.

However, If I do that, I suppose that Elastic will search titles based on the concordance of the letters in the title, rather that the relevance of the proximity between titles.

For example, If my user is a '**barber**', ElasticSearch might suggest '**bartender**', because they have in common: **b,a,r,e,r**

Hence, I have two questions:

1 - is my assumption correct ?

2 - what can I do to add more relevance on my titles search ?

Comment: why you're using autocomplete analyzer?

Comment: I don't know, it's another person who created the initial mapping

Comment: could you show how this autocomplete_analyzer definition looks, just to make sure it does what i expect it to do

Comment: ok I edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your search is following - it uses autocomplete_analyzer, which is basically creates a **huge** index with a lot of n-grams.

Example for `bartender` would be something like `ba`, `bar`, `bart`, etc. 
As you could see, for `barber` you will have a bit similar n-grams, which would make a match.

Regarding your questions, if you would lower the `minimum_should_match` you will get more results, but that's just because the following matching procedure will lead to partial matches.

To increase the relevancy - I would recommend to use another analyzer, since this n-gram analyzer is usually suitable only for **autosuggest** functionality, which isn't the case. There could be several choices from keeping it simple to [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html), or [whitespace](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) one.

What would be more important is to properly construct the query. For example if user searches for partial title, e.g `bar`, you may use [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html). However, if you're searching just by full match (e.g. `developer` or `bartender`) it would be more important to just normalize title field properly. E.g. to use [lowercase analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) with some stemming.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mysterion for your detailed answer :)